# CMakeLists expect to exist

Tags: android, cmake, native

debug|arm64-v8a : expected buildFiles file '\Users\yeetivity\Documents\2023\kth-mobappdev\android-dev\nback_skeletoncode_example\app\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt' to exist
I just tried to open project that include native c module in other computer. When i run the project it gives me that error. Need help . Thanks in advance.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project("nback_cimpl")

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED nback.c)

add_library(JniBridge SHARED JniBridge.c)
find_library(log-lib log )

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${log-lib} )
target_link_libraries(JniBridge PRIVATE ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})